# TypeError: tests is not a function Error in Truffle

Tags: truffle, react, truffle-test

I am following an online tutorial, doing almost exactly like the instructor.

I have the following error every time I try to run 'truffle test'
[image]

my truffle-config file:

```
module.exports = {
  // See <http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration>
  // to customize your Truffle configuration!
  contracts_build_directory: path.join(__dirname, "client/src/contracts"),
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 7545,
      network_id: "*", // match any network
      websockets: true
    }
  },
  contracts_directory: "./client/src/contracts/",
  contracts_build_directory: "./client/src/abis/"
};
```

I tried migrate with --reset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found out that my test code had wrong brackets placement:
it was

```
contract("Marketplace"), accounts => {
  //all tests go inside here

  let marketplace;
  before(async () => {
    marketplace = await Marketplace.deployed();
  });

  //describe comes from Mocha framework
  describe("deployment", async () => {
    it("deploys successfully", async () => {
      const address = await marketplace.address;
      assert.notEqual(address, 0x0);
      assert.notEqual(address, "");
      assert.notEqual(address, null);
      assert.notEqual(address, undefined);
    });
```

it should be

```
contract("Marketplace", accounts => {
  //all tests go inside here

  let marketplace;
  before(async () => {
    marketplace = await Marketplace.deployed(); //this will get the deployed copy of the contract
  });

  //describe comes from Mocha framework
  describe("deployment", async () => {
    it("deploys successfully", async () => {
      const address = await marketplace.address;
      assert.notEqual(address, 0x0);
      assert.notEqual(address, "");
      assert.notEqual(address, null);
      assert.notEqual(address, undefined);
    });
```

notice the bracket after"marketplace" changes everything, the compiler won't complain since in the end of the file I had an extra bracket.

Comment: The snippets of code are identical. Are you sure you pasted the incorrect code? Both are missing several closing brackets `});`.

Comment: The first one has a bracket after contract("Marketplace"

Comment: cool. it works for me